# Annotations Hibernate 3.5

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, hibernate3

The below annotation works when applying it to the field:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=TestMany.class,
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name="TESTID")

private Set<TestMany> testManys = new HashSet<TestMany>();
```

But fails when I place it above the getter below:

```
public Set<TestMany> getTestManys() {
    return testManys;
}
```

With the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: TEST, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(testManys)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1378)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 47 more
```

The Many side of the relationship:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="TESTMANY")
public class TestMany  extends BaseEntityImpl{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="TESTID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Test test;
```

I don't know why it works on the property but not on the getter and it's driving me nuts. The tables are fine and the annotation seems fine to me. Am I missing something very obvious? Could it be a version problem?

There is a basic base class but i dont think this has anything to do with it:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntityImpl implements BaseEntity, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7887314289537012320L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I am using version 3.5.3-Final and 3.2.0.Final for the hibernate-coomons-annotations.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3-Final version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3-Final <version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone have any ideas or experienced something similar? I've spent 2.5 hours of my life trying to fix this one and I predict another 12.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test the solution right now (I'm unfortunately stuck with a computer with less than a quadrillion gigabytes of RAM, so no Hibernate launching here), but as the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) demonstrates, your set needs a type, so instead of:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=TestMany.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="TESTID")
private Set testManys = new HashSet();
```

you use:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="TESTID")
private Set<TestMany> testManys = new HashSet();
```

and it should do the trick. In case you don't like the Hibernate documentation, you might enjoy reading [this](http://josian.wordpress.com/2006/09/09/hibernate-annotations-bidirectional-one-to-many/).

Comment: hi thanks, sorry when i pasted the code the brackets vanished. I am actually doing that :

Comment: private Set<TestMany> testManys = new HashSet<TestMany>();
    
  
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=TestMany.class,
   cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="TESTID")
 public Set<TestMany> getTestManys() {
  return testManys;
 }

Comment: private Set<TestMany> testManys = new HashSet<TestMany>();
    
  
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=TestMany.class,
   cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="TESTID")
 public Set<TestMany> getTestManys() {
  return testManys;
 }

Comment: erm, ignoring the formatting, the annotation do indeed come above the getter but below the field. it is baffling me this one.

Comment: erm. omit the targetEntity part.

Comment: Ok so I changed the Set declaration of the field to a HashSet and it works.

 private HashSet<TestMany> testManys = new HashSet<TestMany>();
    
  
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=TestMany.class,
   cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="TESTID")
 public Set<TestMany> getTestManys() {
  return testManys;
 }

I swear I have declared interface types many times before....... so i dont understand, maybe im going mad.